# How can I fix necessarily wordy overfull \hbox (badness xxxx) errors?

Tags: sectioning, badness

Apparently `\subsection{Impact of the Tiananmen Square Massacre and China's standing in the international community}` gets an `overfull \hbox (0.844 too wide)` message. I didn't know there was a word limit to the subsection argument. What am I supposed to do in this situation? Is there no workaround? The`overfull` however does not impact anything directly. I'm not sure what potential "bad" effects if may even have on my document

Comment: There's no word limit, simply it's a long title in a somewhat large font and TeX can't break the line in an acceptable way. You can reword it or add a manual line break, but without knowing your setup there is not much else anyone can say.

Comment: 0.844pt isn't much, if the heading looks okay you can leave it.

Comment: if your document has long section titles it is usually worth setting things up so they are set raggedright. How that is done depends on how you defined `\subsection` to start with. (You have again provided no example)

Comment: I deleted the texshop tag as this is unrelated to the editor you use to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

The example below produces

```
Overfull \hbox (4.61392pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--5
```

without the `titlesec` package but using it to specify ragged right titles it runs with no warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Impact of the Tiananmen Square Massacre and China's standing in the international community}
zzz

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I have used is force a line break inside the title. Depends on
the package been used, usually `\\` would get the job done.